# Selecting style after using .filter

Tags: javascript

I have an array of divs which are being filtered by an index which we will call
`Resturant.menus` with three different menus

The following will return the configured `display` value for the index

```
console.log(Resturant.menus[0].style.display)
```

However this does not work and throws and undefined exception on `style` when applying the following:

```
console.log(Resturant.menus.filter("." + index).style.display)
```

I noticed in the debugger when simply applying `console.log(Resturant.menus.filter("." + index)` that the div itself is selected and not the object containing all the attributes, it looks like i'm a level to high when using `filter`.  What am I missing to allow selection of `style` when using `filter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `filter` returns a jQuery object. A jQuery collection is a wrapper for selected elements. `style` is a property of the DOM elements, i.e. it's a property of the `HTMLElement` object. In order to use the property you should at first get the element from the collection using either `.get(index)` method or bracket notation `[index]`:

```
Resturant.menus.filter("." + index).get(0).style.display;
Resturant.menus.filter("." + index)[0].style.display;
```

You could also use the `prop` method which returns the specified property of the first element in the collection:

```
Resturant.menus.filter("." + index).prop('style').display;
```

And since you want to get a CSS property using `css` method makes more sense:

```
Resturant.menus.filter("." + index).css('display');
```